# Wrong icon used for Add to Homescreen from Firefox on Android

Tags: android, html, icons, favicon, android-launcher

In my HTML, I followed the guidelines here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons

Currently, I have only 192x192 size icon for my app. My phone is Samsung Galaxy 4 running Android 5.0.1.

With this, Chrome on Android adds the icon correctly to homescreen but Firefox on Android does not. The latter adds a generic "C within a square" icon. See attachment.

Is this a limitation with Firefox? Is there a way to solve this?

[image: Left: from Chrome. Right: from Firefox.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running [RealFaviconGenerator's current favicon compatibility test](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test) with Firefox 58 on a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 7, I get the 180x180 Apple Touch icon:

[image]

What can go wrong with your particular case?

- Your icon is slightly larger, 192x192, whereas the highest resolution defined by Apple is 180x180. In the article you mention, the reason for this is Android Chrome. But now Chrome is using the Web App manifest so this trick is probably outdated.
- Caching issue. Browsers are well-known for reloading icons only when they want to. Maybe you tried various solutions and now Firefox is stuck with an old setup. Use another phone or try again in a few hours.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of RealFaviconGenerator.

Comment: Upgraded Firefox to 58. Same problem of blank icon with a C. Chrome works and it uses 192x192. Don't have an iPhone to test. I cleared the cache and tested.

Comment: One thing you can try is to ask a colleague with an Android and FF to do the same test. You can also uninstall and reinstall FF (... which is especially boring, especially if you have local data such as bookmarks). Again, there is a special place in hell for caching issues about favicon :) . Oh, and if your site is public, what is its address?

Comment: I'm testing on the staging area, which is in a state of flux. I will let you know the URL once I push to production. I will fix this for the next release.

Comment: It works as expected on my Galaxy S7 with latest Firefox. FF is using your touch icon.

Comment: Cool! I guess it's a problem with older phones. Thx for verifying. Best wishes for RealFaviconGenerator